# How to distribute docker-compose files?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've managed to create a docker-compose file which runs my application. Now I'm wondering if there's a standard way for distributing this file? I mean, with docker I would distribute the image uploaded to docker-hub built from my Dockerfile, can I also upload docker-compose files to docker-hub?

What would the deployment flow look like here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can deploy single images on DockerHub
You can't deploy a docker-compose file to DockerHub

The way that I saw the most is :

- Creating a Github repository containing your project (with the
  docker-compose file)
- Explaining how to create the different images in a Readme.md
- Push each images on DockerHub and link your DockerHub images to your
  git repositories to allow people to check the whole stack.

Comment: Ah, so it is through github after all. Thanks a lot!